# Problem login in to a website with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a website using pythons requests module

I've looked into the website using chrome. That's what the post looks like

```
username: aaa
password: aaa
cmd[doStandardAuthentication]: Anmelden
```

this is my code:

```
payload = {
    'username': "noah.kamara",
    'password': "nkitBest1602uNi",
    'cmd[doStandardAuthentication]:': 'Anmelden'
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    login_page = session.get(login_url)
    post = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
    print(post.status_code)
    r = session.get(request_url)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
```

I always get back to the login page and don't know why

Comment: Does it make a post request to the `login_url`?

Comment: Are you sure the payload uses the correct keywords that are declared in the url's html input form?

Comment: The post is made in post = session.post(login_url)

Comment: Yes I’m sure. I’ve provided the payload chrome browser sends

Comment: What is the output of `print(post.status_code)`? Try using `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`.

Comment: Sorry. I took some time off. the output of `post.status_code` is 200, I've tried with json=payload but no success